# C++ visual studio 2015 import dll issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dllimport

I tried to create a win32 project and using dll.

I have received this error when i run the project (0 warnings 0 errors when i build it):
[image: the error i recive]

The procedure I followed was:

1) Create a lib folder and enter my files .lib .dll, and set the .h in the main folder:
[image: the object i add]
2) cange some settings: 
[image: 1° property cange]
[image: 2° property cange]

3) write the import in the odLib.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "trident.h"

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand Why I get a missing error, probably a lack of definition in the project.

Comment: You need to put the missing `dll` into the same folder as your `exe`.  When an application is trying to load any DLLs it requires it only looks in the same  folder as the application and then the PATH (this is different if you are using manifests).

Comment: @RichardCritten I followed your suggestion, but I have received the same system error but is related to Scilib21.dll, Could it be used in cascade from the library I imported?

Comment: You can use utilities such as Dependency Walker or dumpbin to inspect dependencies between dynamic libraries.

Comment: I could be try what @VTT suggests and put them all in the same folder, do not copy any system files.

Answer (score -1):

"put the missing dll into the same folder as your exe. When an application is trying to load any DLLs it requires it only looks in the same folder as the application and then the PATH (this is different if you are using manifests)."

I put the dll in C:\Document\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\odLib\Debug and it work